# Rails inject() doesn't work on an array of one item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this line

```
week[1].inject{ |sum, jog| jog.distance }
```

Which gets the total distance run in `week[1]`, which is an array of `Jog` records. This works when there are multiple records, but if there is only one for that week, `inject` simply returns the record itself, not its distance..

Is there any way for `inject` to work on arrays of single items, the same as larger arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

> **inject(initial, sym) → obj**
>   **inject(sym) → obj**
>   **inject(initial) { |memo, obj| block } → obj**
>   **inject { |memo, obj| block } → obj**
>   [...]
>   If you do not explicitly specify an *initial* value for *memo*, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of *memo*.

So if `a` is a one element array then:

```
a.inject { anything_at_all }
```

is equivalent to

```
a.first
```

This behavior is really just a shortcut to make things like:

```
a.inject(:+)
```

and such quick and easy to say.

If you need your block to always run then you just have to supply the `initial` value and make sure your block does what it needs to do:

```
week[1].inject(0) { |sum, jog| sum + jog.distance }
# -------------^               ^^^^^
# -----------------------------^^^^^
```

Without the `sum +` in the block you'll just end up with `week[1].distance` (assuming you've supplied the `0` initial value of course).

You could also say something like:

```
week[1].map(&:distance).inject(:+)
week[1].map(&:distance).sum
```

to solve the problem another way. You could also do it in the database if you don't need the individual records.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me understand why I've seen `inject(0)` a lot in the past! In the end I found out Rails has a specific `sum` method, so my final code was `week[1].sum { |jog| jog.distance }`